# having problems installing dependencies with yarn or npm

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies, yarnpkg

i cloned a repository and when i try to install the dependencies by typing npm install or yarn i get these errors:

yarn https://gyazo.com/2fdf52c4956df2e565cc0b1cedf24628

npm install https://gyazo.com/a1d197e9ead89dbe4a7d3c5b8f2caa64

does anyone knows how to fix this?

im using windows as you can see, i tried it on my ubuntu system and everything went alright but when i try it in windows i get these errors

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include the text of the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

**The error's in the text**

It looks like the answer is in the error message (screencap from your links included below).

`not found: python2` suggests that python is either not installed or is not in the path.  Python is typically part of *nix builds but Windows systems don't include it out-of-the-box from MSFT.

**What's throwing this error and how can I help it?**

In the comments, there's a question about whether this is a SASS issue.  It's a node-gyp issue and Windows config for that can be touchy.

In the [node-gyp docs for Windows](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows), there are instructions about which software versions are recommended as well as troubleshooting for python which includes setting this npm configuration variable so that node-gyp knows where to find the version of python you have installed:

`npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7`

At this point, if python can be called from a command line *and* the npm config doesn't change the node-gyp errors...it's hard to say what else might be misconfigured.

**Screencap of original error message captured in an image behind a link**

[image: screencap of errors from original link provided in the question]

Comment: tried it and even added it to env path and still gettin the error maybe it has to do something with node-sass ? 

https://gyazo.com/60c77f5cf3e764f042ab3c99f67c6e3a

Comment: The error is from node-gyp, not sass.  See additions to my answer, above.

Comment: by referring to your screenshot, its not unable to find the python path.
try to set the python path before you do npm install or yarn install.
set python by using below command:
set PYTHON=C:\Python27\python.exe    
where C:\Python27\python.exe   is the path where python is installed

Answer (score 0):

Well first we look at where the exception occurs, which is upon looking for a "Python2 executable." If you know anything about python and its interactions with different operating systems, you'll know that Linux distributions (I.E. Ubuntu) come with python installed and configured. On Windows, that is not the case. In order to solve this, you need to install python 2.x, at the time of this writing that is Python 2.7.13. Download here: 
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2713/ 
You will most likely want the MSI installer for your system, depending on if it is 32 or 64 bit. Finally, you have to add the python executable to your environment path so it can be recognized. Instructions can be found here: 
https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-to-add-python-to-the-windows-path

Hope this helps!

Comment: i installed python and added the python exe to my env but still gettin the error i think it has to do something with node-sass what do you think?

https://gyazo.com/60c77f5cf3e764f042ab3c99f67c6e3a

Comment: I am much more familiar with node than yarn, when you run "npm install" do you still get that same error?

Comment: yes look at the original post theres a pictures for both errors yarn and npm

Comment: I saw that, I meant after you added Python2.exe to your system path