# Can anyone help me with this Yarn start and Yarn error (Failed to compile)

Tags: yarnpkg, node-sass

Yarn start:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/index.scss)

Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)

For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
```

Yarn:

```
error E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\node-sass: Command failed.

Exit code: 1

Command: node scripts/build.js

Arguments: 
Directory: E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\node-sass

Output:
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

gyp verb cli [

gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',

gyp verb cli   'E:\\Programing\\Web Development\\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\\tasks\\fe-pair-programming\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',

gyp verb cli   'rebuild',

gyp verb cli   '--verbose',

gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',

gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',

gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',

gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='

gyp verb cli ]

gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0

gyp info using node@16.15.1 | win32 | x64

gyp verb command rebuild []

gyp verb command clean []

gyp verb clean removing "build" directory

gyp verb command configure []

gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH

gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2

gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)

gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)

gyp verb `which` failed     at E (E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)

gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16

gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5

gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5

gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)

gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2

gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)

gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)

gyp verb `which` failed     at E (E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)

gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16

gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5

gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5

gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {

gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'

gyp verb `which` failed }

gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH

gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\Aleksandar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.EXE

gyp ERR! configure error

gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Aleksandar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];

gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1

gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];

gyp ERR! stack                       ^

gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax

gyp ERR! stack

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:398:12)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)

gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)

gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:451:11)

gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)

gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:709:12)

gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000

gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Programing\\Web Development\\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\\tasks\\fe-pair-programming\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="

gyp ERR! cwd E:\Programing\Web Development\pair-programming-frontend-react-main\tasks\fe-pair-programming\node_modules\node-sass

gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.1
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your error, you need python2/python to be able to install the dependencies. If you do not have python2 or python, try installing it and try again. If you do have python2 or python but the program is not picking it up for whatever reason, you can specify the absolute path to python2's python.exe using `yarn config set python /path/to/python2/python.exe` or `npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7`. You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333666/having-problems-installing-dependencies-with-yarn-or-npm).